# Diffence with AnsiString and AnsiString transfered from UnicodeString in C++ builder

Tags: c++, c++builder, unicode-string, c++builder-xe2, ansistring

I am using C++ Builder XE3 and I have met a weird problem with AnsiString.

Just look at below code

```
//Code 1: first time
AnsiString temp1 = "test" ;
funcA(temp1,temp1);

//Code 2: second time    
String uTemp2 = "test";
AnsiString temp2 = uTemp2;
funcA(temp2,temp2);
```

Out of my imagine, it works well in the first time, however it throws a "Bad Format" Exception in the second time. And even I just called funcA once with Code 2 the problem remained.

Since it makes no difference when I ShowMessage within temp1 or temp2. I totally can not understand why the two times of call gave me different results.

funcA is from a 3rd library with a little bit complicated code. So before I trace the code of this library I think I should know what the difference is with Code1 and Code2.

Thanks.

Comment: From what library are the `String` and `AnsiString` classes from?

Comment: These are from C++ Builder XE3

Comment: C++ Builder is an IDE, not a class library.

Comment: @AndréCaron this would be VCL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as `funcA()` is concerned, there is absolutely no difference whether a `char*` or a `UnicodeString` was assigned to the `AnsiString`.  The in-memory representation of the `AnsiString` data is the same in both cases.  So there has to be an issue inside of `funcA()` itself that is causing the error, regardless of how you prepare the `AnsiString`.  But without knowing what `funcA()` actually does and what input it expects, there is no way to diagnose this problem.  you will have to trace the logic inside of `funcA()`.

You say `funcA()` comes from a third-party library.  What kind of library is it exactly?  Is it a statically linked LIB, or an external DLL/BPL?  It makes a big difference.  If it is an external DLL/BPL, then you cannot safely pass non-POD data, such as `AnsiString`, over the DLL boundary unless the DLL/BPL has been compiled with the EXACT SAME compiler, RTL, and Memory Manager as your EXE (in the case of a BPL, that also means enabling Runtime Packages in both BPL and EXE projects).  If that is not the case, then it is likely that the DLL/BPL is using a different RTL/MM that interprets the in-memory `AnsiString` data differently than your EXE does.  The in-memory data of an `AnsiString` was changed in CB2009 to include new fields (namely a codepage and an element size), so if the DLL/BPL was compiled in an earlier compiler version, bad things can happen when it tries to use an `AnsiString` from your newer compiler (and vice versa).

Comment: The library is named Logog. And I made some modification in order to using it with BCB as a static library. And I will try to trace in it.However I still do not understand in what case the results will be different if the inputs are same.

Comment: Your link is right. I just transferred `AnsiString` to `Const Char*` as the argument into its log functions. After tracing the code, I think the difference occurs in `::logog::String& operator= ( const LOGOG_CHAR *  pstr )` (If you are interesting the link of .hpp is http://ppt.cc/Nc-Y) I will try to figure out what happens in it...

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that came to my mind is that there is not an AnsiString from String constructor so that there is no way to assign a String type to an AnsiString.  You do not mention a compiler error so it sounds like the compiler is doing something for you that is the wrong thing.

This posting [How to convert String to AnsiString](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?375155-How-to-convert-String-to-AnsiString) provides a way to do so safely.

Basically you need to reference the String variables char buffer in the assignment so that the compiler will do the right thing.

This is an [older Builder AnsiString reference (1997)](http://bcbjournal.org/articles/vol1/9708/An_AnsiString_class_reference.htm) that provides information about some of the constructors and conversions possible.

Comment: There should be such constructor in C++ Builder (at least after xe2). In fact I can use `temp2 = AnsiString(uTemp2)`. However I still get the same exception.

Comment: @Willy, did you try the method specified in the posting?

Comment: I have read the posting. However in C++ Builder `String` is regarded as `UnicodeString` in default. I think they are different cases.

Comment: This answer is about std::string, the question is about a VCL String